# Time complexity for all subsets using backtracking

Tags: java, subset, backtracking

I am trying to understand the time complexity while using backtracking. The problem is

> Given a set of unique integers, return all possible subsets.
> Eg. Input [1,2,3] would return [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
> I am solving it using backtracking as this:

```
private List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

public List<List<Integer>> getSubsets(int[] nums) {
    
    for (int length = 1; length <= nums.length; length++) { //O(n)
        backtrack(nums, 0, new ArrayList<>(), length);
    }
    result.add(new ArrayList<>());
    return result;
}

private void backtrack(int[] nums, int index, List<Integer> listSoFar, int length) {
    if (length == 0) {
        result.add(listSoFar);
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = index; i < nums.length; i++) { // O(n)
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(); 
        temp.addAll(listSoFar);                 // O(2^n)
        temp.add(nums[i]);
        backtrack(nums, i + 1, temp, length - 1);
    }
}
```

The code works fine, but I am having trouble understanding the time/space complexity.

What I am thinking is here the recursive method is called n times. In each call, it generates the sublist that may contain max 2^n elements. So time and space, both will be O(n x 2^n), is that right?

Is that right? If not, can any one elaborate?

Note that I saw some answers here, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065412/finding-time-complexity-of-backtracking-solution-for-generate-all-subset-problem) but unable to understand. When recursion comes into the picture, I am finding it a bit hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: If you're expecting the result to be all combinations of every length (1-n) I would think the complexity would be something like n * n!

Comment: How would it be n^2? Can you elaborate? Also are you talking about time or space complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right about space complexity. The total space of the final output is O(n*2^n), and this dominates the total space used by the program. The analysis of the time complexity is slightly off though. Optimally, time complexity would, in this case, be the same as the space complexity, but there are a couple inefficiencies here (one of which is that you're not actually backtracking) such that the time complexity is actually O(n^2*2^n) at best.

It can definitely be useful to analyze a recursive algorithm's time complexity in terms of how many times the recursive method is called times how much work each call does. But be careful about saying `backtrack` is only called `n` times: it is called `n` times at the top level, but this is ignoring all the subsequent recursive calls. Also every call at the top level, `backtrack(nums, 0, new ArrayList<>(), length);` is responsible for generating all subsets sized `length`, of which there are `n Choose length`. That is, no single top-level call will ever produce 2^n subsets; it's instead that the sum of `n Choose length` for lengths from 0 to n is 2^n:

[image]

Knowing that across all recursive calls, you generate  2^n subsets, you might then want to ask how much work is done in generating each subset in order to determine the overall complexity. Optimally, this would be O(n), because each subset varies in length from 0 to n, with the average length being n/2, so the overall algorithm might be O(n/2*2^n) = O(n*2^n), but you can't just assume the subsets are generated optimally and that no significant extra work is done.

In your case, you're building subsets through the `listSoFar` variable until it reaches the appropriate length, at which point it is appended to the result. However, `listSoFar` gets copied to a temp list in O(n) time for each of its O(n) characters, so the complexity of generating each subset is O(n^2), which brings the overall complexity to O(n^2*2^n). Also, some `listSoFar` subsets are created which never figure into the final output (you never check to see that there are enough numbers remaining in `nums` to fill `listSoFar` out to the desired `length` before recursing), so you end up doing unnecessary work in building subsets and making recursive calls which will never reach the base case to get appended to `result`, which might also worsen the asymptotic complexity. You can address the first of these inefficiencies with back-tracking, and the second with a simple break statement. I wrote these changes into a JavaScript program, leaving most of the logic the same but re-naming/re-organizing a little bit:

```js
function getSubsets(nums) {
  let subsets = [];
  for (let length = 0; length <= nums.length; length++) {
    // refactored "backtrack" function:
    genSubsetsByLength(length); // O(length*(n Choose length))
  }
  return subsets;

  function genSubsetsByLength(length, i=0, partialSubset=[]) { 
    if (length === 0) {
      subsets.push(partialSubset.slice()); // O(n): copy partial and push to result
      return;
    }
    while (i < nums.length) {
      if (nums.length - i < length) break; // don't build partial results that can't finish
      partialSubset.push(nums[i]); // O(1)
      genSubsetsByLength(length - 1, ++i, partialSubset);
      partialSubset.pop(); // O(1): this is the back-tracking part
    }
  }
}
for (let subset of getSubsets([1, 2, 3])) console.log(`[`, ...subset, ']');
```

The key difference is using back-tracking to avoid making copies of the partial subset every time you add a new element to it, such that each is built in O(length) = O(n) time rather than O(n^2) time, because there is now only O(1) work done per element added. Popping off the last character added to the partial result after each recursive call allows you to re-use the same array across recursive calls, thus avoiding the O(n) overhead of making `temp` copies for each call. This, along with the fact that only subsets which appear in the final output are built, allows you to analyze the total time complexity in terms of the total number of elements across all subsets in the output: O(n*2^n).

Comment: Thank you for this! I think I am getting it, though still need to spend some time and write it out to completely get it!

Comment: @Ufder No problem! If there are any particular parts that are still unclear after you work through it feel free to ask.

Comment: Just got through the explanation, and makes sense! I understand the change to add the element from `listSoFar`, pass it in recursion and remove that element for the next iteration to have the same `listSoFar`. One follow up question though, say I am looking at your `genSubsetsByLength`, I would say its O(2^n) because I know thats the time complexity for generating subsets. However, how do I deduce it from the function? ie the branching factor is 2 and height is n? (2 is possibly because an element can be present or absent, but not clear looking at `for`). In any case, thank you for the help!

Comment: @Ufder technically, `genSubsetsByLength(length=k)` (or the `backtrack(..., length=k)` function call) is O(n\* n Choose k) because each top-level call is only generating subsets sized `k` (not all 2^n subsets) and there are `n Choose k` subsets sized `k`, each length `O(n)`. All of the calls from lengths from 0 to `n` in `getSubsets` together generate the 2^n subsets.

Comment: It's kind of hard to analyze `genSubsetsByLength` in terms of a recursion tree directly from the code, because the number of branches varies from call to call and level to level (the branching factor of `genSubsetsByLength(k, i, partial)` being `(n-i)`). As `i` is being incremented before every call, each recursive call spawns one fewer call than its parent, and you get a branching structure involving factorial functions.

Comment: `backtrack` and `genSubsetsByLength` are the exact same algorithms/processes you would use to generate size k combinations from a collection of `n` elements, and I did do some analysis of the structure of the recursion tree for this algorithm in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70146962/how-do-i-compute-the-complexity-of-a-combination-function/70150573#70150573) if you want to have a look at it.

Comment: You could write a powerset generation algorithm in a different way though, where the complexity would be a lot easier to analyze in terms of a recursion tree. Basically, you walk down the list of all `n` elements and make 2 recursive calls for each element: one which includes that element in the partial subset being generated, and one that doesn't. At the bottom level of the tree you copy the partial result to a result list in O(n) time. This leads to a depth `n` recursion tree with branching factor `2`, each doing `O(n)` work at the bottom level, making it O(n\*2^n) (which is optimal).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works not efficiently.

Like first solution in the link, you only think about the number will be included or not. (like getting combination)

It means, you don't have to iterate in getSubsets and backtrack function.
"backtrack" function could iterate "nums" array with parameter

```java
private List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
public List<List<Integer>> getSubsets(int[] nums) {
    
    backtrack(nums, 0, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
    return result;
}

private void backtrack(int[] nums, int index, List<Integer> listSoFar) 
// This function time complexity 2^N, because will search all cases when the number included or not
{
    if (index == nums.length) {
        result.add(listSoFar);
        return;
    }
    
    // exclude num[index] in the subset 
    backtrack(nums, index+1, listSoFar)
    // include num[index] in the subset
    backtrack(nums, index+1, listSoFar.add(nums[index]))
}
```

Comment: I wanted to understand the time complexity of the code I posted, was not looking for optimal or alternative solutions. Also this code produces wrong answer. The include call should be before the exclude call and the result should add a `new ArrayList<>(listSoFar)` from all elements of listSoFar. Thanks for trying to help, but please verify your solution before posting!