# Time Complexity of DFS in logest increasing path in a matrix

Tags: java, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I came across a problem to find the longest increasing path in a matrix. The Brute-Force solution to it is pretty straight forward:

```
public class Solution {

  private static final int[][] dirs = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};
  private int m, n;

  public int longestIncreasingPath(int[][] matrix) {
      if (matrix.length == 0) return 0;
      m = matrix.length;
      n = matrix[0].length;
      int ans = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
          for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
              ans = Math.max(ans, dfs(matrix, i, j));
      return ans;
  }

  private int dfs(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
      int ans = 0;
      for (int[] d : dirs) {
          int x = i + d[0], y = j + d[1];
          if (0 <= x && x < m && 0 <= y && y < n && matrix[x][y] > matrix[i][j])
              ans = Math.max(ans, dfs(matrix, x, y));
      }
      return ++ans;
  }
}
```

And the time complexity for this was given as `O(2^(m+n))` where m is no. of rows, and n is no. of cols in the matrix.

I'm having a hard time understanding this. The first nested for loop is `O(mn)` which is fine. Now each cell is treated as a root, and a DFS is done on it. However the time complexity for a DFS is `O(V + E)`, and here `V = mn and E = 4*mn`, so each dfs should be `O(mn)`, so the total time complexity should be `O(mn) x O(mn) = O(m^2.n^2)` right?

Note: I am aware that this is not an optimal solution and this can be memoized, however my question is about understanding time complexity in this brute for method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DFS isn't O(V+E) = O(nm) because you don't have a visited set. Without this set, the paths your various branches take can overlap and duplicate work such that you can potentially explore the same vertices and traverse the same edges many times over from any given DFS call from `longestIncreasingPath`. A memory-less search with a branching factor of 4 is what causes exponential behavior.

For example, consider the potential worst case of a perfectly convex matrix:

```
6 5 4 3 4 5 6
5 4 3 2 3 4 5
4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
3 2 1 0 1 2 3
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
5 4 3 2 3 4 5
6 5 4 3 4 5 6
```

The worst case path for any vertex you search is to climb diagonally to the nearest corner, and such paths are O((n+m)/2) steps long. Every vertex has up to 4 options, and as there's no shared memory in the form of a visited set between recursive calls, you get a naive 4^((n+m)/2) = 2^(n+m) worst-case complexity for DFS. It would be more precise to say that most vertices in this worst case scenario only have 2 to 3 viable neighbors to recurse into, such that the actual worst-case complexity for each search would be between sqrt(2)^(n+m) and sqrt(3)^(n+m), but the exponential run-time is the same.

If you had a visited set, you would get a complexity more like the one you alluded to in your answer. It would be O(nm*((n+m)/2)) = O(n^2*m + m^2*n) because of the restriction that paths be increasing, but without that restriction it would be O((nm)^2).

Comment: Also note: I believe the real worst-case complexity of the provided algorithm would be O(nm*2^(n+m)) because you run the DFS on every node of the matrix, but this doesn't make a huge difference.

Comment: Memoization would have the same practical effect of including a visited set.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing explanation! It is starting to make sense. Still a bit unclear about O((n+m)/2). Does it mean that if I draw a tree with a node that has 4 children, then such a tree would have depth of O((n+m)/2)?

Comment: @Ufder Basically, yeah. You can analyze DFS as on O(b^d) algorithm, where `b` is the average branching factor and `d` is the average depth. The worst case average `b` value for this algorithm is obtained in a convex matrix like in the example I gave, where every node besides those on the edge of the matrix has multiple branches the DFS could take. The `d` value as the average DFS depth for such a matrix is O((n+m)/2) = O(n+m), because the path from any node to the top of its local gradient is at most (n+m)/2 (as is the case with the center vertex).

Comment: You could try to analyze the worst-case complexity in terms of the sorts of matrices which would maximize `d` rather than `b` (as in one that snakes values, like [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],...], with `d = nm/2`, but `b = 1`), but I don't think you could engineer one that would produce a worst case complexity for the DFS algorithm as O(b^d) worse than O(2^(n+m))

Comment: Got it. The `O(b^d)` insight helps, I think I get it now. Random question, how do you know all this? As in, how can I improve my understanding to this level.

Comment: @Ufder I wouldn't say I'm an expert, but having taken a couple algorithms and data structures classes has helped, of course in terms of learning the basic concepts and techniques, but more importantly in getting practice proving these sorts things for yourself. I think that when you're studying algorithms (or anything math-y), practicing explaining *why* a result holds or why an algorithm works, and formally proving it to yourself when you can, develops more understanding in the long-term as it generalizes better to understanding new problems than simply memorizing any particular result does.

Comment: I am clear on this now. If I had taken a corner cell, and calculate longestPath to the opposite corner, then that would be `(n+m)` length with a branching factor of 2 (as its a corner cell), so that still comes back to `2^(m+n)`. Thanks once again, and appreciate the insight!

Comment: Sorry that I am shameliessly hijacking you on this, but would you spare a couple of minutes on another question I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877504/time-complexity-for-all-subsets-using-backtracking.